# Is $\|x\|^6 \sin^6 \|x\|^6$ harmonic?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose the function 
$$ u(x)=\|x\|^6 \sin^6 \|x\|^6$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, where 
$$\|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots +x_d^2}.$$ 
How can I decide if the function $u$ is harmonic in the unit ball $B_1(0)$ without calculating $\Delta u$?

Comment: Harmonic functions have a very convenient property related to some integral.

Comment: Seems rather devilish to me.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do you mean the equation $$0 = \frac{1}{\omega_d} \int_{B_1(0)} \|y\|^6 \sin^6 \|y\|^6 \, \text{d}\lambda(y)?$$
But how can I calculate this integral?

Comment: I mean that, and the trick is that you don't need to compute the integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Harmonic functions have the mean value property: For all small enough $r > 0$

$$u(x) = \frac{1}{\omega_{d-1}\cdot r^{d-1}} \int_{\lVert y-x\rVert = r} u(y)\,dS(y),$$

where $\omega_k$ is the $k$-dimensional volume of the $k$-dimensional unit sphere, and $dS$ is the surface measure on the sphere.

Here, we have

$$u(0) = 0 < \frac{1}{\omega_{d-1}\cdot r^{d-1}}\int_{\lVert y\rVert = r} u(y)\,dS(y)$$

for $0 < r < \pi^{1/6}$, since $u(y) > 0$ on that sphere.

Comment: And this means the function is not harmonic. Is this correct?

Comment: Right. It doesn't have the mean value property, hence it isn't harmonic.

Comment: And you used that $\sin x > 0$ for $x \in (0,\pi)$.